# I am not getting data while working with angular with web api by seperate service

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

It is `services.js` file which is getting data from server. I have main script file that while is not getting the data into the main java script method form services layer.

> Blockquote

Please check the code, and if I have any mistake please let me know:

```
app.factory("studentServices", function ($http)## 



----------


 ##
 return {

        postData: function (student) {

            $http.post("/api/Student/Register", student)
              .then(function (response) {
                console.info(response.data);

                debugger;
                return response.data;

            }, function (error) {

                console.info("error in reruest");
            });
        },
        getData: function () {
            debugger;
            var rt;
            $http.get("/api/Student/getStudent").then(function (response) {
                console.info(response.data);
                debugger;
                rt=response.data;
            }, function (error) { console.info("error in geting"); })
            debugger;
            return rt;
        }

        }
    })
```

"here is other servise for factory"

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="script.js" />
var app = angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, studentServices) {
    debugger;
    console.info("init");

    $scope.addStudent = function () {
        console.info("just");
        console.info($scope.id);
        $scope.result="";
        var student = {id:$scope.id,name:$scope.name,email:$scope.email,college:$scope.college,mobile:$scope.mobile}
        console.info(student);
      //  $http.post("/api/Student/Register", student).then(function (response) {
        //    console.info(response.data);
        $scope.result = studentServices.postData(student);
            console.info("result " + $scope.result);
            get();
       // }, function (error) { console.info("error in reruest") })
        //$scope.getStudents();
    }


    $scope.getStudents = function get() {
        debugger;
            console.info("gettinf studetn list");
        //    $http.get("/api/Student/getStudent").then(function (response) {
        //      console.info(response.data);
            var local = studentServices.getData();
            debugger;
            $scope.students = local;  //response.data;
            debugger;
            console.info("getdata list  ");

    //        }, function (error) { console.info("error in geting") })

        }
        console.info("last");

})
```

Comment: where you calling your factory methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct below things :

1.In your factory method just return the api promise. for example:

```
postData: function (student) { 
    return  $http.post("/api/Student/Register", student);
}
```

2.In your controller consume the factory method and its response:
for example:

```
studentServices.postData(student).then(function (result){    
    $scope.result = result.data;
}, function(error){
    // handle error
})
```

Do similar for `getData`.

Since `$http` is async, you have to resolve data in controller, so get data. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owj5chz8/),

Comment: why we need to return it we are retuning inside the function

Comment: @teja: because `$http is asynchronous`, the $scope is accepting data before the call is complete. which is null,. So no data in $scope. you have to resolve it in the controller to assign the data.